# Is io.on('connection') event necessary to send data to a pre-existing & connected socket?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have 2 Nodejs Server script running namely: StudentServer & AdminServer both on different ports on same IP.

I have a connected socket ID (lets assume it is **SCKT-X0**) saved in Database which was retrieved in StudentServer. There is no problem communicating via **SCKT-X0** from the StudentServer.

The StudentServer is registered to the event: `io.on('connection')` because it serves the client side in realtime and it is completely working.
The AdminServer does not have a `io.on('connection')` event.

I am trying to push data through **SCKT-X0** from **AdminServer** using the following code:

```
if (io.sockets.connected[client.id]){
    io.to(client.id).emit("event", {"data": data});
}else{
    console.log("Client not connected");
}
```

**Conclusion:** The client.id is **SCKT-X0** which is connected beacuse it is receiving data from **StudentServer** without any change in Socket ID. But when the above code runs, it outputs `Client not connected` from the **AdminServer**.

**So my Questions are:**

1. Do i need to register io.on('connection') event to communicate with a 
   pre-existing and connected socket ID (which was retrieved in another server)?
2. If the answer to **Question 1** is positive then, does socketIO references different clients with same SocketID for different Servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is socket.io specific question and this could change but  io.on('connection') is a mechanism to indicate that some client is connected. To answer number 1, yes Admin Server needs it to push data to all its client. Think of it as observer pattern. If SCKT-X0 is not registered as connected to AdminServer then even if you have the ID it will not be pushed to the client.

You need something like a Redis Server to share it across different servers. Luckily there is already an adapter made by socket.io

https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-redis

Comment: So do i need to add `io.adapter(redisAdapter({ pubClient: cluster, subClient: cluster }));` to both my server scripts?

Comment: depends on your need but you can simply use this on both server scripts for simple usage. `io.adapter(redisAdapter({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 }));`